# How do I move a point's y coordinate to intersect with a line?

Tags: javascript, geometry

[image]

I have point `c`, which represents the center of a circle. After I drag the circle, I want its y coordinate `hmm` to snap to a line that's drawn between point `a` and `b`. How do I solve for `hmm`?

So far I've been able to find the midway `y` value between points `a` and `b`. However, it's not taking into account point `c`'s `x` value.:

```
const snapYToLine = (aY, bY) => {
  const yDist = bY - aY;
  return aY + (yDist * 0.5);
}

const a = { x: 10, y: 10 };
const b = { x: 50, y: 30 };
const c = { x: 20, y: 0 }; // not doing anything with this yet...

const hmm = snapYToLine(a.y, b.y); // will need to include c.x here...
console.log(hmm);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X` coordinate of `C` depends on where you drag it, but `Y` coordinate should be so point stays on line between `A` and `B`?

The equation of line between 2 points (A and B):
`(x - Xa) / (Xa - Xb) = (y - Ya) / (Ya - Yb)`.

So `hmm` = `(x - Xa) * (Ya - Yb) / (Xa - Xb) + Ya`.

Because it's equation of line you can drag point `C` over `A`/`B` `X` coordinates and still find corresponsive `Y` value.

Hope I've understood your question right.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. For future reference, I recommend replacing `(x - Xa)` with `(Xc - Xa)`.